# Android App: How to loadUrl in WebView from another class?

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I´m quite new to Android app programming and Java. I want my App to use a WebView for showing all what is needed. The user can click on an HTML-Button or Link an this sends a request to my Android java class, for example to show another page.

Therefor I have my main class loading the Webview like this:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/status01.html");
```

In the `public class JavaScriptInterface` I want to have a function loading another URL:

```
public void showOffers() {
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) ((Activity) mContext).findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/offers.html");
}
```

But this doesn´t compile because: `Activity cannot be resolved to a type`

How can I access the WebView from my JavaScriptInterface class to load another URL?

Answer (score 2):

Define the class `JavaScriptInterface` as inner class of your `Activity` and store the reference to the `WebView` as member variable of your `Activity`.

Because inner classes can access member variables of the class they are defined in, you can change your code to this:

```
MyWebActivity extends Activity{
    private WebView myWebView;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(), "Android");
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/status01.html");
    }

    private class JavaScriptInterface{
        JavaScriptInterface(){
        }
        public void showOffers() {                
            myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/offers.html");
        }
    }
}
```